# Next.js: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm new to Next.js and I have encountered an error as below:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Formik`.
```

**my Login component**

```
export const Login = () => {
const { LoginUser, isFetching, loginError } = useContext(UserContext)
console.log(loginError)
return (
    <>
        <Formik
            validationSchema={LoginValidationSchema}
            initialValues={{
                email: "",
                password: "",
            }}
            onSubmit={(values) => {
                LoginUser(values);
                console.log(values)
            }}
        >
            {() => (
                <>
                    <div className='w-full relative h-screen max-h-screen'>
                        <div className='absolute py-2'>
                            <Link href="/" className="text-3xl font-bold py-2">title</Link>
                        </div>
                        <Form className='w-full h-full flex flex-col justify-center items-center'>
                            <div className='flex flex-col bg-gray-200 mx-1 xsm:px-10 px-5 py-5 w-auto xsm:w-[350px] rounded'>
                                <div className='border-b-[2px] border-gray-400 py-2'>
                                    <h1 className='font-semibold text-3xl'>Welcome back</h1>
                                    <h1 className='font-light text-xl'>Login</h1>
                                </div>
                                <div className='flex flex-col'>
                                    <div className='flex mt-2 flex-col'>
                                        <label className='font-semibold' htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                                        <Field type="email" className="px-3 outline-none focus:ring-2 ring-offset-2 ring-offset-gray-200 ring-btnColor font-semibold rounded py-2 bg-white" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                                        <ErrorMessage component="p" className='text-red-600 font-semibold' name="email" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className='flex mt-2 flex-col'>
                                        <label className='font-semibold' htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                                        <Field type="password" className="px-3 outline-none focus:ring-2 ring-offset-2 ring-offset-gray-200 ring-btnColor font-semibold rounded py-2 bg-white" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
                                        <ErrorMessage component="p" className='text-red-600 font-semibold' name="password" />
                                    </div>
                                    <Link href="/login/forgot_password" className='px-1 py-2 font-medium hover:underline hover:text-btnColor w-fit' >Forgot password</Link>
                                    <button type='submit' disabled={isFetching} className="font-semibold select-none mt-4 text-white rounded px-2 py-2 bg-btnColor disabled:opacity-40 disabled:cursor-not-allowed">{isFetching ? "Submitting" : "Submit"}</button>
                                </div>
                                <p className='font-semibold mt-3'>If you don't have an account <Link href="auth/signup" className='text-btnColor hover:text-indigo-500'>signup</Link></p>
                            </div>
                        </Form>
                    </div>
                </>
            )}
        </Formik>
    </>
)
```

}

I don't understand what the error message is implying, I am exporting the login component by default, and I have no other exports, when I remove the formik component and use the normal form and input's the last part of the error becomes `` Check the render method of `Login` `` instead of `` Check the render method of `Formik` ``

Comment: Why do you have to wrap the JSX in a function ?  Simply put it inside the Formik component?

Comment: the error has changed to Check the render method of `Login` after removing it, but what if i need to use ``setFieldValue`` or values how would i access them